# Constraining conditional summation in Bounded Optimization in Python

Tags: scipy-optimize, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization, minimize, gekko

I am trying to minimize a the sum of least squares subject to certain constraints.  For the most part, this problem seems fairly straightforward except for one constraint.  I'm having a difficult time figuring out a way of modeling the constraint that the sum of all values greater than a given number cannot exceed a constant value.

I currently have a working solution that iterates through the possible combinations and picks the best solution with scipy's minimize function.  However, this solution is not the most efficient in terms of time (or computing power).  Is there another way of approaching this problem that makes it possible to solve in a single pass?

I've been looking at Gekko as it makes the general code much more readable, but once I add an equation that uses a summation, the efficiency is worse than looping.

[image: Formula]

Python (scipy) code:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def _func(self, w, w_bar):
        """
        Objective function - minimize the difference of squares between
        w_bar and w
        """
        error = np.sum([(w_bar[i] - w[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(w))])
        return error


def _func_deriv(self, w, w_bar):
    """
    Derivative of the objective function
    """
    gradiant = [-2 * (w_bar[i] - w[i]) for i in range(len(w))]
    return gradiant

display_solver_output = True
epsilon = 1E-13
tolerance = 1E-16

w_bar = <List of decimal values>

optimal_solution = []
optimal_tracking_error = float("inf")

total_time = 0.0

default_bounds = [(0, 0.3) for i in range(len(w_bar))]

initial_guess = [min(w_bar[i], 0.3) for i in range(len(w_bar))]

max_iterations = int(0.6 / 0.06) + 1
for j in range(max_iterations):
    constraints = (\
        {# Equality Constraint: where the equality is of the form C_j(x) = 0
            'type': 'eq',
            'fun' : lambda w: np.sum(w) - 1
        },
        {# Inequality Constraint: where the inequality is of the form C_j(x) >= 0
            'type': 'ineq',
            'fun' : lambda w: -1 * np.sum(w[-j:]) + 0.6
        })

    # create bounds from the default bounds
    bounds = default_bounds[:]
    # set upper bounds for all 'small' w
    for i in range(len(w_bar) - j):
        bounds[i] = (bounds[i][0], 0.06)

    try:

        start = time.time()

        res = minimize(_func,
                        initial_guess, # Initial Guess/Seed
                        args=w_bar,
                        jac=_func_deriv,
                        bounds=bounds,
                        constraints=constraints,
                        tol=tolerance,
                        options=\
                        {
                            #'maxiter': 100,
                            'disp': display_solver_output
                        })

        end = time.time()

        total_time += end - start

        if display_solver_output:
            print(f"Solution Time: {end-start} s")
            print(f"Total Time: {total_time} s\n")

        if res.success:
            # check to see if the result is within our acceptable range
            # (expected_value +- epsilon)
            passes_large = sum([wl for wl in res.x if wl > 0.06]) <= (0.6 + epsilon)
            passes_sum_weights_one = abs(sum(res.x) - 1) <= epsilon

            # current solution is best solution if it is better than
            # previous best solution
            if (passes_large and passes_sum_weights_one and res.fun < optimal_tracking_error):
                optimal_tracking_error = res.fun
                optimal_solution = res.x

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Gekko code:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

w_bar = <List of decimal values>

model = GEKKO(remote=False)

w = model.Array(model.Var, len(w_bar), lb=0, ub=0.3)

# Sum of all values = 1
model.Equation(model.sum(w) == 1)

# Sum of all values greater than 6% cannot exceed 60%
# This is the part that degrades the speed greatly
model.Equation(model.sum([model.if3(w[i] - 0.06, 0, w[i]) for i in range(len(w))]) <= 0.6)

model.Minimize(model.sum([(w_bar[i] - w[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(w_bar))]))

model.solve()
```

With scipy, I created a loop where I explicitly indicate if the value is subject to the constraint.  It works but it is slow.  For large inputs (300+), it takes about 10 sec.

In Gekko, I added an equation to constrain but this degrades the performance greatly.  For small amount of input, it run relatively quickly (under 1 sec), but once there are more than 300 inputs the time to solve increases to about 90 seconds.

Am I thinking about the equations properly?  Do I need to reshape this problem somehow?

Data set 1 - w_bar: (Works well)

```
0.0000290098720682487343868705,
0.0000723827066008387518299476,
0.0002072744176096173915822705,
0.0003672809435335959934840107,
0.0003752484336042253846688711,
0.0004405565779129329566220824,
0.0005525596498762783855459046,
0.0006728198725774592129480554,
0.0008351912653287541643826696,
0.0009825084042287753464578806,
0.0009948648777755642828519691,
0.0012517612267766885632838162,
0.0013546692913343326698875246,
0.0015307554230129220783373226,
0.0018079051888007421049402691,
0.0018273451279460959651328143,
0.0019106018091149384691427602,
0.0019397417543016734988324706,
0.0021105212741847910173045113,
0.0025270382452472284845495592,
0.0026030268201749619505495437,
0.0026381414030341878249837264,
0.0035891127645570676979108904,
0.0042890768176753193003852561,
0.0054266187080476129436017240,
0.0072342421507922666121696771,
0.0141269512168524993586417500,
0.0277835377270709998751732016,
0.0358112813055125623355637036,
0.4222060446840235199334703797,
0.4525019300404232987113785672
```

Data set 1 - Expected Results

```
0.00029009872068244083,
0.0007238270660083144,
0.002072744176096174,
0.003672809435335925,
0.003752484336042254,
0.004405565779129317,
0.0055255964987627705,
0.006728198725774593,
0.008351912653287517,
0.009825084042287735,
0.009948648777755588,
0.012517612267766834,
0.013546692913343296,
0.014123432102475512,
0.014400581868263323,
0.01442002180740866,
0.014503278488577536,
0.01453241843376423,
0.014703197953647362,
0.015119714924709763,
0.0151957034996375,
0.015230818082496761,
0.016181789444019656,
0.016881753497137882,
0.01801929538751016,
0.019826918830254826,
0.02671962789631506,
0.04037621440653355,
0.04840395798497512,
0.3,
0.3
```

Data set 2 - w_bar: (does not work well)

```
0.000007815875,
0.000008941521,
0.000009627394,
0.000010762907,
0.000011539940,
0.000011822949,
0.000012052014,
0.000012526334,
0.000013414645,
0.000013932927,
0.000013955431,
0.000015010769,
0.000015721501,
0.000015847039,
0.000017499261,
0.000017740886,
0.000022409018,
0.000023446383,
0.000023769321,
0.000025218211,
0.000026432503,
0.000029219318,
0.000030326871,
0.000030598632,
0.000030767053,
0.000032463081,
0.000034340788,
0.000039307435,
0.000041047637,
0.000042717492,
0.000043676212,
0.000044110066,
0.000044188176,
0.000044540981,
0.000045730008,
0.000047201637,
0.000048350816,
0.000049262536,
0.000052023657,
0.000053054453,
0.000056020848,
0.000058046508,
0.000063947874,
0.000067167499,
0.000069187263,
0.000071131270,
0.000071613326,
0.000072761127,
0.000073458337,
0.000074730372,
0.000079639189,
0.000084199573,
0.000084603561,
0.000089676063,
0.000090002613,
0.000090250728,
0.000090958865,
0.000091780483,
0.000094820916,
0.000096386941,
0.000097951562,
0.000098087729,
0.000098285781,
0.000099286808,
0.000100880981,
0.000112384492,
0.000113020079,
0.000119654507,
0.000119844927,
0.000121917556,
0.000125752295,
0.000127115137,
0.000128301202,
0.000128434254,
0.000131136836,
0.000136985654,
0.000137451057,
0.000137892405,
0.000138478238,
0.000138510178,
0.000140286393,
0.000141644129,
0.000143025370,
0.000145684057,
0.000146128282,
0.000149165998,
0.000152928119,
0.000158011782,
0.000163334650,
0.000163993685,
0.000165146865,
0.000165346542,
0.000165727164,
0.000166763187,
0.000167570306,
0.000167701282,
0.000168187959,
0.000168466851,
0.000171537576,
0.000174634817,
0.000175208593,
0.000176437493,
0.000177213028,
0.000178471925,
0.000179304250,
0.000181361576,
0.000181774556,
0.000182317630,
0.000184348532,
0.000185496791,
0.000186600111,
0.000186986147,
0.000187895217,
0.000189050126,
0.000190311524,
0.000191188576,
0.000192708902,
0.000193427219,
0.000194377568,
0.000195221574,
0.000198353309,
0.000199150740,
0.000200669882,
0.000201329466,
0.000202603999,
0.000202840576,
0.000205243564,
0.000205267618,
0.000206280289,
0.000207180107,
0.000207403834,
0.000207693968,
0.000208319663,
0.000210918430,
0.000213097112,
0.000213808958,
0.000216127148,
0.000219614612,
0.000219958232,
0.000220138310,
0.000222035657,
0.000222401415,
0.000222760998,
0.000227509090,
0.000227596620,
0.000228951334,
0.000229255220,
0.000234511344,
0.000236992905,
0.000237318329,
0.000237794112,
0.000241724793,
0.000244140378,
0.000245108625,
0.000245348717,
0.000248554774,
0.000248622886,
0.000249551658,
0.000249917107,
0.000251383144,
0.000252364867,
0.000252518485,
0.000253298440,
0.000253519628,
0.000253894898,
0.000254257568,
0.000254474702,
0.000255773762,
0.000258142697,
0.000258694891,
0.000259473672,
0.000263981063,
0.000265385129,
0.000265929045,
0.000267164327,
0.000273901777,
0.000277254717,
0.000278234965,
0.000278852360,
0.000283459901,
0.000289070649,
0.000291372423,
0.000295603226,
0.000301966065,
0.000303991670,
0.000304363077,
0.000305384930,
0.000311071976,
0.000311670131,
0.000312786000,
0.000314656110,
0.000316524766,
0.000325310734,
0.000331275522,
0.000336062292,
0.000338832600,
0.000340484394,
0.000342036718,
0.000357296061,
0.000357704298,
0.000357937771,
0.000358446109,
0.000359799583,
0.000359998968,
0.000361527417,
0.000362966939,
0.000364820190,
0.000374621447,
0.000386212038,
0.000387148965,
0.000387832733,
0.000387999956,
0.000388426165,
0.000388865023,
0.000389427459,
0.000389902480,
0.000393306999,
0.000396066587,
0.000396212999,
0.000400014580,
0.000400166845,
0.000404149671,
0.000411878348,
0.000414328908,
0.000417213521,
0.000420034700,
0.000423594466,
0.000424079830,
0.000426916906,
0.000427907197,
0.000428596411,
0.000447038030,
0.000465801486,
0.000466707081,
0.000486192543,
0.000492689659,
0.000497607736,
0.000499009449,
0.000502225035,
0.000509876067,
0.000512491653,
0.000526893703,
0.000544232360,
0.000551226109,
0.000553362405,
0.000554621217,
0.000555323671,
0.000566235583,
0.000568858650,
0.000585816740,
0.000595444454,
0.000595676538,
0.000596027082,
0.000601532816,
0.000603398396,
0.000603875830,
0.000604469221,
0.000618072836,
0.000618924385,
0.000633748912,
0.000638051121,
0.000638063264,
0.000646909261,
0.000648598715,
0.000650473629,
0.000681635898,
0.000688663096,
0.000695006176,
0.000698233309,
0.000698315251,
0.000705518120,
0.000714561173,
0.000732850381,
0.000751384305,
0.000759306513,
0.000762051797,
0.000762449955,
0.000763277577,
0.000777398792,
0.000804723486,
0.000806123103,
0.000811382583,
0.000826331403,
0.000863195543,
0.000885311967,
0.000888494491,
0.000905345436,
0.000906955857,
0.000913376383,
0.000919577290,
0.000945443427,
0.000953607106,
0.000960165048,
0.000967380780,
0.000986657560,
0.001013995795,
0.001035286884,
0.001040623463,
0.001042209681,
0.001054608040,
0.001097461414,
0.001123190067,
0.001151108539,
0.001174213778,
0.001179660877,
0.001236145549,
0.001262545378,
0.001319707705,
0.001407165160,
0.001408158461,
0.001449382306,
0.001505208285,
0.001525693275,
0.001545857137,
0.001548823775,
0.001604079926,
0.001631439516,
0.001662684683,
0.001664953145,
0.001670337051,
0.001681930216,
0.001721041622,
0.001772208339,
0.001814347121,
0.001857630106,
0.001999227026,
0.002000140185,
0.002059968093,
0.002073217095,
0.002076366149,
0.002087479476,
0.002212095863,
0.002213487143,
0.002226900538,
0.002240316849,
0.002245926943,
0.002397677381,
0.002409873183,
0.002433426457,
0.002533656116,
0.002554175483,
0.002702565798,
0.002725149141,
0.002862990738,
0.003012626379,
0.003106708313,
0.003166477317,
0.003311416707,
0.003376595359,
0.003389236791,
0.003394227968,
0.003447322975,
0.003564280055,
0.003693253982,
0.003760854305,
0.003789602821,
0.003812877852,
0.004221260332,
0.004573300544,
0.004682578946,
0.004872355381,
0.004894274971,
0.005046232120,
0.005583382792,
0.005638003076,
0.005814559667,
0.006184242380,
0.007007230181,
0.007892807911,
0.008176775716,
0.009132843479,
0.011816355808,
0.015919697299,
0.017167705703,
0.018201374196,
0.019553531484,
0.019770204022,
0.020634517885,
0.020672075448,
0.022999345332,
0.034482186306,
0.037620656622,
0.052245806915,
0.061315610525,
0.131015009271,
0.161722678961
```

Data set 2 - Expected Results

```
7.815875e-05,
8.941521e-05,
9.627393999999998e-05,
0.00010762907,
0.00011539939999999982,
0.00011822948999999979,
0.00012052014,
0.00012526333999999986,
0.00013414645,
0.00013932926999999957,
0.00013955431,
0.0001495835059119702,
0.000150294237911998,
0.00015041977591199324,
0.00015207199791202302,
0.000152313622912043,
0.00015698175491200684,
0.00015801911991201296,
0.00015834205791202864,
0.00015979094791202398,
0.00016100523991198663,
0.00016379205491198664,
0.0001648996079119817,
0.0001651713689119893,
0.00016533978991200703,
0.00016703581791202901,
0.00016891352491201118,
0.00017388017191200737,
0.00017562037391202252,
0.00017729022891198592,
0.00017824894891204157,
0.00017868280291200405,
0.00017876091291208266,
0.00017911371791199957,
0.00018030274491195414,
0.00018177437391201945,
0.000182923552912061,
0.00018383527291203298,
0.00018659639391205675,
0.00018762718991203147,
0.00019059358491195527,
0.0001926192449119648,
0.00019852061091196402,
0.00020174023591201703,
0.00020375999991193355,
0.00020570400691193437,
0.00020618606291200375,
0.00020733386391192797,
0.00020803107391205626,
0.0002093031089120231,
0.00021421192591195874,
0.00021877230991197577,
0.00021917629791203723,
0.0002242487999119585,
0.00022457534991197144,
0.00022482346491199185,
0.00022553160191199193,
0.0002263532199120038,
0.00022939365291196605,
0.0002309596779119836,
0.00023252429891199093,
0.00023266046591194687,
0.00023285851791200062,
0.00023385954491204357,
0.00023545371791194143,
0.0002469572289119646,
0.00024759281591200586,
0.0002542272439119975,
0.0002544176639119319,
0.00025649029291192915,
0.0002603250319119855,
0.0002616878739119835,
0.000262873938912035,
0.0002630069909120449,
0.0002657095729119685,
0.00027155839091206046,
0.00027202379391202676,
0.0002724651419120668,
0.0002730509749120375,
0.00027308291491199606,
0.00027485912991198353,
0.0002762168659120024,
0.0002775981069120444,
0.00028025679391200156,
0.0002807010189120066,
0.00028373873491202133,
0.0002875008559119559,
0.000292584518912039,
0.0002979073869119615,
0.00029856642191202376,
0.0002997196019119469,
0.00029991927891203,
0.0003002999009120056,
0.0003013359239119744,
0.0003021430429120131,
0.0003022740189120128,
0.0003027606959119818,
0.0003030395879120486,
0.00030611031291202025,
0.0003092075539120183,
0.00030978132991203765,
0.00031101022991204873,
0.0003117857649120417,
0.0003130446619119617,
0.000313876986911976,
0.00031593431291201474,
0.0003163472929119965,
0.0003168903669120422,
0.00031892126891197917,
0.00032006952791199296,
0.0003211728479119738,
0.0003215588839120256,
0.0003224679539119852,
0.00032362286291197145,
0.00032488426091201736,
0.0003257613129119702,
0.00032728163891202416,
0.0003279999559120312,
0.0003289503049119891,
0.00032979431091203777,
0.00033292604591197614,
0.0003337234769120466,
0.00033524261891200056,
0.0003359022029119755,
0.0003371767359120057,
0.0003374133129120084,
0.0003398163009119851,
0.0003398403549120571,
0.00034085302591201603,
0.0003417528439120266,
0.0003419765709120092,
0.000342266704911983,
0.00034289239991205385,
0.00034549116691198653,
0.00034766984891196443,
0.0003483816949120069,
0.0003506998849119761,
0.00035418734891205084,
0.00035453096891195537,
0.0003547110469119837,
0.00035660839391197575,
0.0003569741519120372,
0.0003573337349120194,
0.00036208182691197064,
0.0003621693569119687,
0.0003635240709120471,
0.0003638279569120289,
0.00036908408091199313,
0.00037156564191204633,
0.0003718910659120154,
0.00037236684891197506,
0.00037629752991198565,
0.0003787131149120248,
0.00037968136191196647,
0.0003799214539119949,
0.0003831275109120432,
0.0003831956229120269,
0.00038412439491202323,
0.00038448984391204334,
0.00038595588091199304,
0.00038693760391196466,
0.00038709122191198455,
0.0003878711769119594,
0.0003880923649119783,
0.0003884676349119532,
0.00038883030491203654,
0.000389047438912041,
0.00039034649891200916,
0.00039271543391198124,
0.0003932676279120183,
0.0003940464089119744,
0.0003985537999119681,
0.00039995786591199667,
0.00040050178191201354,
0.0004017370639120306,
0.0004084745139119775,
0.00041182745391203234,
0.0004128077019120334,
0.0004134250969120184,
0.0004180326379120275,
0.00042364338591197536,
0.00042594515991198806,
0.00043017596291201876,
0.00043653880191198266,
0.00043856440691201305,
0.0004389358139119734,
0.00043995766691204343,
0.0004456447129119721,
0.0004462428679119628,
0.0004473587369120003,
0.0004492288469120187,
0.0004510975029120407,
0.0004598834709119715,
0.0004658482589120257,
0.0004706350289119652,
0.000473405336911973,
0.00047505713091202815,
0.0004766094549119654,
0.0004918687979119956,
0.0004922770349119918,
0.0004925105079119638,
0.0004930188459120279,
0.0004943723199119822,
0.0004945717049119815,
0.0004961001539120082,
0.0004975396759119774,
0.0004993929269120327,
0.0005091941839120283,
0.0005207847749119795,
0.0005217217019120183,
0.0005224054699119622,
0.0005225726929119816,
0.0005229989019119875,
0.0005234377599120318,
0.0005240001959119908,
0.0005244752169120295,
0.0005278797359120326,
0.0005306393239119781,
0.0005307857359119724,
0.0005345873169119753,
0.0005347395819119778,
0.0005387224079120155,
0.000546451084912013,
0.00054890164491197,
0.0005517862579119822,
0.0005546074369120173,
0.0005581672029120285,
0.0005586525669119659,
0.0005614896429120325,
0.0005624799339119684,
0.0005631691479120259,
0.0005816107669119913,
0.0006003742229120048,
0.0006012798179119884,
0.0006207652799119849,
0.0006272623959120036,
0.0006321804729119897,
0.0006335821859119923,
0.000636797771912025,
0.0006444488039119931,
0.0006470643899120163,
0.0006614664399119813,
0.0006788050969119976,
0.0006857988459120204,
0.0006879351419119665,
0.0006891939539120166,
0.0006898964079119804,
0.0007008083199120062,
0.0007034313869120015,
0.0007203894769119833,
0.0007300171909120018,
0.00073024927491201,
0.0007305998189119847,
0.0007361055529120149,
0.0007379711329119846,
0.0007384485669120252,
0.0007390419579119909,
0.0007526455729120031,
0.0007534971219120086,
0.0007683216489120074,
0.0007726238579120136,
0.0007726360009119909,
0.0007814819979120094,
0.0007831714519120047,
0.0007850463659119877,
0.0008162086349119961,
0.0008232358329119806,
0.0008295789129119884,
0.0008328060459119852,
0.0008328879879120103,
0.000840090856911989,
0.0008491339099119937,
0.0008674231179120169,
0.0008859570419120222,
0.0008938792499119844,
0.0008966245339119852,
0.0008970226919120021,
0.0008978503139120199,
0.00091197152891202,
0.0009392962229119841,
0.0009406958399119855,
0.000945955319912013,
0.0009609041399120041,
0.0009977682799120165,
0.0010198847039119786,
0.0010230672279119826,
0.0010399181729120084,
0.0010415285939120026,
0.001047949119911996,
0.0010541500269119941,
0.0010800161639119834,
0.001088179842911993,
0.001094737784912012,
0.0011019535169120112,
0.001121230296912,
0.0011485685319119845,
0.001169859620911995,
0.001175196199911988,
0.0011767824179119955,
0.001189180776912008,
0.00123203415091198,
0.0012577628039120029,
0.001285681275911981,
0.0013087865149120157,
0.001314233613911996,
0.0013707182859119997,
0.0013971181149119995,
0.0014542804419119865,
0.0015417378969120117,
0.0015427311979119846,
0.0015839550429120077,
0.0016397810219120137,
0.0016602660119119995,
0.0016804298739120022,
0.0016833965119119854,
0.0017386526629119892,
0.0017660122529120081,
0.0017972574199120023,
0.0017995258819119972,
0.0018049097879120027,
0.0018165029529119917,
0.001855614358911993,
0.0019067810759119958,
0.0019489198579120096,
0.0019922028429119935,
0.0021337997629119866,
0.0021347129219119907,
0.002194540829911992,
0.002207789831911997,
0.0022109388859119913,
0.0022220522129120074,
0.0023466685999120026,
0.002348059879911988,
0.0023614732749120005,
0.0023748895859120045,
0.002380499679912001,
0.0025322501179119907,
0.0025444459199120014,
0.002567999193912005,
0.002668228852911991,
0.002688748219911994,
0.002837138534911992,
0.0028597218779120056,
0.0029975634749119964,
0.003147199115911993,
0.0032412810499120024,
0.0033010500539119992,
0.0034459894439119996,
0.0035111680959119995,
0.003523809527911996,
0.003528800704912003,
0.003581895711911993,
0.003698852791912005,
0.003827826718911997,
0.0038954270419120007,
0.003924175557911998,
0.003947450588911994,
0.004355833068911996,
0.004707873280912004,
0.004817151682911996,
0.005006928117911997,
0.005028847707912001,
0.005180804856911993,
0.005717955528911997,
0.005772575812911997,
0.005949132403911996,
0.006318815116911996,
0.007141802917911999,
0.008027380647911999,
0.008311348452911996,
0.009267416215911995,
0.011950928544912,
0.016054270035912,
0.017302278439912003,
0.018335946932911996,
0.019688104220911995,
0.019904776758911995,
0.020769090621911995,
0.020806648184911996,
0.023133918068911997,
0.034616759042912,
0.037755229358912,
0.052380379651911994,
0.061450183261912,
0.131149582007912,
0.161857251697912
```

---

[image: Least-Squares vs Abs Diff] with slightly tighter constraints

- `w_bar` are the input values
- `w` represents the absolute difference
- `E(w)` represents the least-squares difference

Comment: Show your scipy code? Also please show a semi-realistic list of values for `w_bar`.

Comment: Please also show realistic values for const 1, const 2, etc.

Comment: Just realized that the 2nd example set isn't a good example with the current constraints.  If you lower the bounds then it will work better.

Example, (1) 0 <= w <= 0.2; (2) SUM(w >= 0.04) <= 0.4

Comment: What are the horizontal and vertical axes on your plot?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a rush with creating it and didn’t label.  The horizontal axis is index of `i` and the vertical axis is the value of that index, ranging from 0 - 1.  

The values are arranged such that w_bar[i-1] <= w_bar[i] <= w_bar[i+1].

Comment: Can you show it in semilog y, and as a lineplot instead of scatter? Currently the linear scale and scatter obscures a lot of the data.

Comment: Updated graph per your request of semilog y and lineplot.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't see least-squares being a clear win over least-absolute: for some values, least-squares is better (23-27), and for some values it's worse (3, 18, 28, 29). At the risk of sounding stubborn, I've still not heard a convincing argument that the cost function needs to be non-linear for it to be valid in this use case.

Comment: `w_bar` is the full weight of a particular security in a basket where the SUM(w_bar) = 1.  Due to certain restrictions, it may not be feasible to hold that particular weight.  The objective here is to create another basket with different weights that matches the original as closely as possible with constraints in place.  This means if the original values of w_bar are `w_bar[i-1] <= w_bar[i] <= w_bar[i+1]` then the new basket must also have this property.  The quadratic approach holds this property while the absolute difference does not.

Comment: That's called monotonicity, and it's stated nowhere in your initial model equations, so you couldn't magically expect that to hold true, least-squares or otherwise. I've demonstrated how to add a monotonic constraint in my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know there was a special term for that.  Really appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you give up on the idea of least-squares, so that you can instead frame this as a mixed-integer linear program. It's slightly tricky, but it does work. Setup up variables for:

- `|err|`, the absolute value of `w - w_bar`, to be minimized
- `w`, to be bounded in (0, 0.3)
- `whi`, equal to `w` if it's above const1, otherwise 0
- `ishi`, a binary indicating whether w > const1

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse as sp


def make_constraints(
    w_bar: np.ndarray,
    const1: float,
    const2: float,
    w_max: float,
) -> tuple[LinearConstraint, ...]:
    n = w_bar.size

    # Constrain error to absolute difference of w and wbar
    # err >= w - wbar: -err + w <= wbar
    # err >= wbar - w:  err + w >= wbar
    err_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.bmat((
            (-sp.eye(n), sp.eye(n), sp.csc_array((n, 2 * n))),
            (sp.eye(n), sp.eye(n), sp.csc_array((n, 2 * n))),
        ), format='csc'),
        lb=np.concatenate((np.full(n, -np.inf), w_bar)),
        ub=np.concatenate((w_bar, np.full(n, np.inf))),
    )

    # sum w = 1
    one_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack((np.zeros((1, n)), np.ones(n), np.zeros(2 * n)), format='csc'),
        lb=1, ub=1,
    )

    # Activate ishi based on value of w and const1
    # ishi >= w - const1: w - ishi <= const1
    # ishi <= w/const1:   w/const1 - ishi >= 0
    ishi_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.bmat((
            (sp.csc_array((n, n)), sp.eye(n), sp.csc_array((n, n)), -sp.eye(n)),
            (sp.csc_array((n, n)), sp.eye(n) / const1, sp.csc_array((n, n)), -sp.eye(n)),
        ), format='csc'),
        lb=np.concatenate((
            np.full(n, -np.inf),
            np.zeros(n),
        )),
        ub=np.concatenate((
            np.full(n, const1),
            np.full(n, np.inf),
        )),
    )

    # Constrain whi based on whether ishi is set
    # whi <= w                  w - whi          >= 0
    # whi <= ishi*M                -whi + M*ishi >= 0
    # whi >= w - M*(1 - ishi)   w - whi + M*ishi <= M
    M = 2 * w_max
    whi_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.bmat((
            (sp.csc_array((n, n)), sp.eye(n), -sp.eye(n), sp.csc_array((n, n))),
            (sp.csc_array((n, n)), sp.csc_array((n, n)), -sp.eye(n), M * sp.eye(n)),
            (sp.csc_array((n, n)), sp.eye(n), -sp.eye(n), M * sp.eye(n)),
        ), format='csc'),
        lb=np.concatenate((
            np.zeros(n),
            np.zeros(n),
            np.full(n, -np.inf),
        )),
        ub=np.concatenate((
            np.full(n, np.inf),
            np.full(n, np.inf),
            np.full(n, M),
        )),
    )

    # Constrain whi sum based on value of const2
    # sum whi <= const2
    whisum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack((
            sp.csc_array((1, n)), sp.csc_array((1, n)), np.ones(n), sp.csc_array((1, n)),
        ), format='csc'),
        lb=-np.inf, ub=const2,
    )

    # w[i] <= w[i + 1]: -w[i] + w[i + 1]  >= 0
    monotonicity = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack((
            sp.csc_array((n - 1, n)),
            sp.eye(m=n - 1, n=n, k=1) - sp.eye(m=n - 1, n=n, k=0),
            sp.csc_array((n - 1, n)),
            sp.csc_array((n - 1, n)),
        )),
        lb=0, ub=np.inf,
    )

    return (
        err_constraint, one_constraint,
        ishi_constraint, whi_constraint, whisum_constraint,
        monotonicity,
    )


def solve(
    w_bar: np.ndarray,
    const1: float = 0.06,
    const2: float = 0.6,
    w_max: float = 0.3,
) -> tuple[
    float,       # cost
    np.ndarray,  # err
    np.ndarray,  # w
    np.ndarray,  # whi
    np.ndarray,  # ishi
]:
    n = w_bar.size

    # Variables: n |err|, n w, n whi, n ishi
    c = np.concatenate((
        np.ones(n),   # minimize |err|
        np.zeros(3*n),  # don't optimize w, whi or ishi
    ))

    # err, w, whi continuous, ishi integral
    integrality = np.zeros(shape=4*n, dtype=np.uint8)
    integrality[-n:] = 1

    bounds = Bounds(
        #                  |err|,     w,    whi, ishi
        lb=np.repeat((-np.inf,     0,      0, 0), n),
        ub=np.repeat((+np.inf, w_max, np.inf, 1), n),
    )

    constraints = make_constraints(w_bar, const1, const2, w_max)

    result = milp(
        c=c, integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints,
    )
    assert result.success, result.message
    err, w, whi, ishi = np.split(result.x, (n, 2*n, 3*n))
    return result.fun, err, w, whi, ishi


def solve_and_output(w_bar: np.ndarray, ax: plt.Axes, label: str) -> None:
    const2 = 0.6
    cost, err, w, whi, ishi = solve(w_bar, const2=const2)

    print(f'Cost: {cost:.3f}')
    print(f'Sum: {w.sum():.2f} == 1')
    print(f'const2: {whi.sum():.2f} <= {const2}')
    print()

    ax.plot(w_bar, w, label=label)


def make_data() -> tuple[np.ndarray, ...]:
    data_1 = (
        0.0000290098720682487343868705,
        0.0000723827066008387518299476,
        0.0002072744176096173915822705,
        0.0003672809435335959934840107,
        0.0003752484336042253846688711,
        0.0004405565779129329566220824,
        0.0005525596498762783855459046,
        0.0006728198725774592129480554,
        0.0008351912653287541643826696,
        0.0009825084042287753464578806,
        0.0009948648777755642828519691,
        0.0012517612267766885632838162,
        0.0013546692913343326698875246,
        0.0015307554230129220783373226,
        0.0018079051888007421049402691,
        0.0018273451279460959651328143,
        0.0019106018091149384691427602,
        0.0019397417543016734988324706,
        0.0021105212741847910173045113,
        0.0025270382452472284845495592,
        0.0026030268201749619505495437,
        0.0026381414030341878249837264,
        0.0035891127645570676979108904,
        0.0042890768176753193003852561,
        0.0054266187080476129436017240,
        0.0072342421507922666121696771,
        0.0141269512168524993586417500,
        0.0277835377270709998751732016,
        0.0358112813055125623355637036,
        0.4222060446840235199334703797,
        0.4525019300404232987113785672,
    )

    data_2 = (
        0.000007815875,
        0.000008941521,
        0.000009627394,
        0.000010762907,
        0.000011539940,
        0.000011822949,
        0.000012052014,
        0.000012526334,
        0.000013414645,
        0.000013932927,
        0.000013955431,
        0.000015010769,
        0.000015721501,
        0.000015847039,
        0.000017499261,
        0.000017740886,
        0.000022409018,
        0.000023446383,
        0.000023769321,
        0.000025218211,
        0.000026432503,
        0.000029219318,
        0.000030326871,
        0.000030598632,
        0.000030767053,
        0.000032463081,
        0.000034340788,
        0.000039307435,
        0.000041047637,
        0.000042717492,
        0.000043676212,
        0.000044110066,
        0.000044188176,
        0.000044540981,
        0.000045730008,
        0.000047201637,
        0.000048350816,
        0.000049262536,
        0.000052023657,
        0.000053054453,
        0.000056020848,
        0.000058046508,
        0.000063947874,
        0.000067167499,
        0.000069187263,
        0.000071131270,
        0.000071613326,
        0.000072761127,
        0.000073458337,
        0.000074730372,
        0.000079639189,
        0.000084199573,
        0.000084603561,
        0.000089676063,
        0.000090002613,
        0.000090250728,
        0.000090958865,
        0.000091780483,
        0.000094820916,
        0.000096386941,
        0.000097951562,
        0.000098087729,
        0.000098285781,
        0.000099286808,
        0.000100880981,
        0.000112384492,
        0.000113020079,
        0.000119654507,
        0.000119844927,
        0.000121917556,
        0.000125752295,
        0.000127115137,
        0.000128301202,
        0.000128434254,
        0.000131136836,
        0.000136985654,
        0.000137451057,
        0.000137892405,
        0.000138478238,
        0.000138510178,
        0.000140286393,
        0.000141644129,
        0.000143025370,
        0.000145684057,
        0.000146128282,
        0.000149165998,
        0.000152928119,
        0.000158011782,
        0.000163334650,
        0.000163993685,
        0.000165146865,
        0.000165346542,
        0.000165727164,
        0.000166763187,
        0.000167570306,
        0.000167701282,
        0.000168187959,
        0.000168466851,
        0.000171537576,
        0.000174634817,
        0.000175208593,
        0.000176437493,
        0.000177213028,
        0.000178471925,
        0.000179304250,
        0.000181361576,
        0.000181774556,
        0.000182317630,
        0.000184348532,
        0.000185496791,
        0.000186600111,
        0.000186986147,
        0.000187895217,
        0.000189050126,
        0.000190311524,
        0.000191188576,
        0.000192708902,
        0.000193427219,
        0.000194377568,
        0.000195221574,
        0.000198353309,
        0.000199150740,
        0.000200669882,
        0.000201329466,
        0.000202603999,
        0.000202840576,
        0.000205243564,
        0.000205267618,
        0.000206280289,
        0.000207180107,
        0.000207403834,
        0.000207693968,
        0.000208319663,
        0.000210918430,
        0.000213097112,
        0.000213808958,
        0.000216127148,
        0.000219614612,
        0.000219958232,
        0.000220138310,
        0.000222035657,
        0.000222401415,
        0.000222760998,
        0.000227509090,
        0.000227596620,
        0.000228951334,
        0.000229255220,
        0.000234511344,
        0.000236992905,
        0.000237318329,
        0.000237794112,
        0.000241724793,
        0.000244140378,
        0.000245108625,
        0.000245348717,
        0.000248554774,
        0.000248622886,
        0.000249551658,
        0.000249917107,
        0.000251383144,
        0.000252364867,
        0.000252518485,
        0.000253298440,
        0.000253519628,
        0.000253894898,
        0.000254257568,
        0.000254474702,
        0.000255773762,
        0.000258142697,
        0.000258694891,
        0.000259473672,
        0.000263981063,
        0.000265385129,
        0.000265929045,
        0.000267164327,
        0.000273901777,
        0.000277254717,
        0.000278234965,
        0.000278852360,
        0.000283459901,
        0.000289070649,
        0.000291372423,
        0.000295603226,
        0.000301966065,
        0.000303991670,
        0.000304363077,
        0.000305384930,
        0.000311071976,
        0.000311670131,
        0.000312786000,
        0.000314656110,
        0.000316524766,
        0.000325310734,
        0.000331275522,
        0.000336062292,
        0.000338832600,
        0.000340484394,
        0.000342036718,
        0.000357296061,
        0.000357704298,
        0.000357937771,
        0.000358446109,
        0.000359799583,
        0.000359998968,
        0.000361527417,
        0.000362966939,
        0.000364820190,
        0.000374621447,
        0.000386212038,
        0.000387148965,
        0.000387832733,
        0.000387999956,
        0.000388426165,
        0.000388865023,
        0.000389427459,
        0.000389902480,
        0.000393306999,
        0.000396066587,
        0.000396212999,
        0.000400014580,
        0.000400166845,
        0.000404149671,
        0.000411878348,
        0.000414328908,
        0.000417213521,
        0.000420034700,
        0.000423594466,
        0.000424079830,
        0.000426916906,
        0.000427907197,
        0.000428596411,
        0.000447038030,
        0.000465801486,
        0.000466707081,
        0.000486192543,
        0.000492689659,
        0.000497607736,
        0.000499009449,
        0.000502225035,
        0.000509876067,
        0.000512491653,
        0.000526893703,
        0.000544232360,
        0.000551226109,
        0.000553362405,
        0.000554621217,
        0.000555323671,
        0.000566235583,
        0.000568858650,
        0.000585816740,
        0.000595444454,
        0.000595676538,
        0.000596027082,
        0.000601532816,
        0.000603398396,
        0.000603875830,
        0.000604469221,
        0.000618072836,
        0.000618924385,
        0.000633748912,
        0.000638051121,
        0.000638063264,
        0.000646909261,
        0.000648598715,
        0.000650473629,
        0.000681635898,
        0.000688663096,
        0.000695006176,
        0.000698233309,
        0.000698315251,
        0.000705518120,
        0.000714561173,
        0.000732850381,
        0.000751384305,
        0.000759306513,
        0.000762051797,
        0.000762449955,
        0.000763277577,
        0.000777398792,
        0.000804723486,
        0.000806123103,
        0.000811382583,
        0.000826331403,
        0.000863195543,
        0.000885311967,
        0.000888494491,
        0.000905345436,
        0.000906955857,
        0.000913376383,
        0.000919577290,
        0.000945443427,
        0.000953607106,
        0.000960165048,
        0.000967380780,
        0.000986657560,
        0.001013995795,
        0.001035286884,
        0.001040623463,
        0.001042209681,
        0.001054608040,
        0.001097461414,
        0.001123190067,
        0.001151108539,
        0.001174213778,
        0.001179660877,
        0.001236145549,
        0.001262545378,
        0.001319707705,
        0.001407165160,
        0.001408158461,
        0.001449382306,
        0.001505208285,
        0.001525693275,
        0.001545857137,
        0.001548823775,
        0.001604079926,
        0.001631439516,
        0.001662684683,
        0.001664953145,
        0.001670337051,
        0.001681930216,
        0.001721041622,
        0.001772208339,
        0.001814347121,
        0.001857630106,
        0.001999227026,
        0.002000140185,
        0.002059968093,
        0.002073217095,
        0.002076366149,
        0.002087479476,
        0.002212095863,
        0.002213487143,
        0.002226900538,
        0.002240316849,
        0.002245926943,
        0.002397677381,
        0.002409873183,
        0.002433426457,
        0.002533656116,
        0.002554175483,
        0.002702565798,
        0.002725149141,
        0.002862990738,
        0.003012626379,
        0.003106708313,
        0.003166477317,
        0.003311416707,
        0.003376595359,
        0.003389236791,
        0.003394227968,
        0.003447322975,
        0.003564280055,
        0.003693253982,
        0.003760854305,
        0.003789602821,
        0.003812877852,
        0.004221260332,
        0.004573300544,
        0.004682578946,
        0.004872355381,
        0.004894274971,
        0.005046232120,
        0.005583382792,
        0.005638003076,
        0.005814559667,
        0.006184242380,
        0.007007230181,
        0.007892807911,
        0.008176775716,
        0.009132843479,
        0.011816355808,
        0.015919697299,
        0.017167705703,
        0.018201374196,
        0.019553531484,
        0.019770204022,
        0.020634517885,
        0.020672075448,
        0.022999345332,
        0.034482186306,
        0.037620656622,
        0.052245806915,
        0.061315610525,
        0.131015009271,
        0.161722678961,
    )

    return np.array(data_1), np.array(data_2)


def main() -> None:
    data_1, data_2 = make_data()

    ax: plt.Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xmin = min(data_1.min(), data_2.min())
    xmax = max(data_1.max(), data_2.max())
    ax.plot(
        [xmin, xmax],
        [xmin, xmax],
        'g--', label='ideal',
    )

    for w_bar, label in (
        (data_1, 'Dataset 1'),
        (data_2, 'Dataset 2'),
    ):
        solve_and_output(w_bar, ax, label=label)

    ax.set_title('Linear fit, all datasets')
    ax.set_xlabel('w_bar')
    ax.set_ylabel('w_fit')
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Cost: 0.549
Sum: 1.00 == 1
const2: 0.60 <= 0.6

Cost: 0.052
Sum: 1.00 == 1
const2: 0.35 <= 0.6
```

[image: monotonic fit]

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This does work very quickly.  Unfortunately I cannot give up on using least-squares and instead use absolute difference.  I've added more information to the summary.

Comment: What is the reason that least squares is needed?

Comment: Trying to match to the weights in a collection as close as possible while staying in the constraints.  Curve smoothing.

Comment: That's what this does - just in a linear fashion, not a quadratic fashion. Have you tried it on your data?

Comment: Yes, I added a graph to the data above showing the difference between the linear and quadratic approaches.  `w` = linear and `E(w)` = quadratic.  You can see the difference near on the right side of the x-axis.

Comment: In an ordered fashion... w_bar(i-1) <= w_bar(i) <= w_bar(i+1) and then w(i-1) <= w(i) <= w(i+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `m.if2()` instead of `m.if3()` to use continuous instead of discrete optimization. The `m.if3()` function can take much longer for a larger number of binary decision variables.

```py
model.sum([model.if2(w[i] - 0.06, 0, w[i])
```

[image: Solution]

If it needs to fit at the lower magnitude values, try normalizing by `w_bar`:

```py
model.sum([((w_bar[i] - w[i])/w_bar[i])** 2
```

[image: Normalized]

Here is a full script that produces the results (not normalized).

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w_bar = [0.000007815875,0.000008941521,0.000009627394,0.000010762907,0.000011539940,\
0.000011822949,0.000012052014,0.000012526334,0.000013414645,0.000013932927,0.000013955431,\
0.000015010769,0.000015721501,0.000015847039,0.000017499261,0.000017740886,0.000022409018,\
0.000023446383,0.000023769321,0.000025218211,0.000026432503,0.000029219318,0.000030326871,\
0.000030598632,0.000030767053,0.000032463081,0.000034340788,0.000039307435,0.000041047637,\
0.000042717492,0.000043676212,0.000044110066,0.000044188176,0.000044540981,0.000045730008,\
0.000047201637,0.000048350816,0.000049262536,0.000052023657,0.000053054453,0.000056020848,\
0.000058046508,0.000063947874,0.000067167499,0.000069187263,0.000071131270,0.000071613326,\
0.000072761127,0.000073458337,0.000074730372,0.000079639189,0.000084199573,0.000084603561,\
0.000089676063,0.000090002613,0.000090250728,0.000090958865,0.000091780483,0.000094820916,\
0.000096386941,0.000097951562,0.000098087729,0.000098285781,0.000099286808,0.000100880981,\
0.000112384492,0.000113020079,0.000119654507,0.000119844927,0.000121917556,0.000125752295,\
0.000127115137,0.000128301202,0.000128434254,0.000131136836,0.000136985654,0.000137451057,\
0.000137892405,0.000138478238,0.000138510178,0.000140286393,0.000141644129,0.000143025370,\
0.000145684057,0.000146128282,0.000149165998,0.000152928119,0.000158011782,0.000163334650,\
0.000163993685,0.000165146865,0.000165346542,0.000165727164,0.000166763187,0.000167570306,\
0.000167701282,0.000168187959,0.000168466851,0.000171537576,0.000174634817,0.000175208593,\
0.000176437493,0.000177213028,0.000178471925,0.000179304250,0.000181361576,0.000181774556,\
0.000182317630,0.000184348532,0.000185496791,0.000186600111,0.000186986147,0.000187895217,\
0.000189050126,0.000190311524,0.000191188576,0.000192708902,0.000193427219,0.000194377568,\
0.000195221574,0.000198353309,0.000199150740,0.000200669882,0.000201329466,0.000202603999,\
0.000202840576,0.000205243564,0.000205267618,0.000206280289,0.000207180107,0.000207403834,\
0.000207693968,0.000208319663,0.000210918430,0.000213097112,0.000213808958,0.000216127148,\
0.000219614612,0.000219958232,0.000220138310,0.000222035657,0.000222401415,0.000222760998,\
0.000227509090,0.000227596620,0.000228951334,0.000229255220,0.000234511344,0.000236992905,\
0.000237318329,0.000237794112,0.000241724793,0.000244140378,0.000245108625,0.000245348717,\
0.000248554774,0.000248622886,0.000249551658,0.000249917107,0.000251383144,0.000252364867,\
0.000252518485,0.000253298440,0.000253519628,0.000253894898,0.000254257568,0.000254474702,\
0.000255773762,0.000258142697,0.000258694891,0.000259473672,0.000263981063,0.000265385129,\
0.000265929045,0.000267164327,0.000273901777,0.000277254717,0.000278234965,0.000278852360,\
0.000283459901,0.000289070649,0.000291372423,0.000295603226,0.000301966065,0.000303991670,\
0.000304363077,0.000305384930,0.000311071976,0.000311670131,0.000312786000,0.000314656110,\
0.000316524766,0.000325310734,0.000331275522,0.000336062292,0.000338832600,0.000340484394,\
0.000342036718,0.000357296061,0.000357704298,0.000357937771,0.000358446109,0.000359799583,\
0.000359998968,0.000361527417,0.000362966939,0.000364820190,0.000374621447,0.000386212038,\
0.000387148965,0.000387832733,0.000387999956,0.000388426165,0.000388865023,0.000389427459,\
0.000389902480,0.000393306999,0.000396066587,0.000396212999,0.000400014580,0.000400166845,\
0.000404149671,0.000411878348,0.000414328908,0.000417213521,0.000420034700,0.000423594466,\
0.000424079830,0.000426916906,0.000427907197,0.000428596411,0.000447038030,0.000465801486,\
0.000466707081,0.000486192543,0.000492689659,0.000497607736,0.000499009449,0.000502225035,\
0.000509876067,0.000512491653,0.000526893703,0.000544232360,0.000551226109,0.000553362405,\
0.000554621217,0.000555323671,0.000566235583,0.000568858650,0.000585816740,0.000595444454,\
0.000595676538,0.000596027082,0.000601532816,0.000603398396,0.000603875830,0.000604469221,\
0.000618072836,0.000618924385,0.000633748912,0.000638051121,0.000638063264,0.000646909261,\
0.000648598715,0.000650473629,0.000681635898,0.000688663096,0.000695006176,0.000698233309,\
0.000698315251,0.000705518120,0.000714561173,0.000732850381,0.000751384305,0.000759306513,\
0.000762051797,0.000762449955,0.000763277577,0.000777398792,0.000804723486,0.000806123103,\
0.000811382583,0.000826331403,0.000863195543,0.000885311967,0.000888494491,0.000905345436,\
0.000906955857,0.000913376383,0.000919577290,0.000945443427,0.000953607106,0.000960165048,\
0.000967380780,0.000986657560,0.001013995795,0.001035286884,0.001040623463,0.001042209681,\
0.001054608040,0.001097461414,0.001123190067,0.001151108539,0.001174213778,0.001179660877,\
0.001236145549,0.001262545378,0.001319707705,0.001407165160,0.001408158461,0.001449382306,\
0.001505208285,0.001525693275,0.001545857137,0.001548823775,0.001604079926,0.001631439516,\
0.001662684683,0.001664953145,0.001670337051,0.001681930216,0.001721041622,0.001772208339,\
0.001814347121,0.001857630106,0.001999227026,0.002000140185,0.002059968093,0.002073217095,\
0.002076366149,0.002087479476,0.002212095863,0.002213487143,0.002226900538,0.002240316849,\
0.002245926943,0.002397677381,0.002409873183,0.002433426457,0.002533656116,0.002554175483,\
0.002702565798,0.002725149141,0.002862990738,0.003012626379,0.003106708313,0.003166477317,\
0.003311416707,0.003376595359,0.003389236791,0.003394227968,0.003447322975,0.003564280055,\
0.003693253982,0.003760854305,0.003789602821,0.003812877852,0.004221260332,0.004573300544,\
0.004682578946,0.004872355381,0.004894274971,0.005046232120,0.005583382792,0.005638003076,\
0.005814559667,0.006184242380,0.007007230181,0.007892807911,0.008176775716,0.009132843479,\
0.011816355808,0.015919697299,0.017167705703,0.018201374196,0.019553531484,0.019770204022,\
0.020634517885,0.020672075448,0.022999345332,0.034482186306,0.037620656622,0.052245806915,\
0.061315610525,0.131015009271,0.161722678961]

model = GEKKO(remote=False)

w = model.Array(model.Var, len(w_bar), lb=0, ub=0.3)

# Sum of all values = 1
model.Equation(model.sum(w) == 1)

# Sum of all values greater than 6% cannot exceed 60%
# This is the part that degrades the speed greatly
model.Equation(model.sum([model.if2(w[i] - 0.06, 0, w[i]) for i in range(len(w))]) <= 0.6)

model.Minimize(model.sum([(w_bar[i] - w[i])** 2 for i in range(len(w_bar))]))

model.options.SOLVER=3
model.solve()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
w_sol = [w[i].value[0] for i in range(len(w_bar))]
plt.semilogy(w_bar,label='w_bar')
plt.semilogy(w_sol,label='w')
plt.xlabel('index'); plt.ylabel('value[index]')
plt.tight_layout(); plt.grid(); plt.savefig('results.png')
plt.show()
```

The `m.if2()` function can have problems converging, especially if values are at the switching point because it creates a saddle point that is difficult for optimizers. If this doesn't work, I recommend calculating a solution with `m.if2()` and then use that to initialize a problem using `m.if3()`. There is [additional information](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions) on the `m.if2()` function (MPCC) and `m.if3()` (binary switching).